# How to find the current number of tor relays/ exit nodes in entire tor network?

Tags: relays, exit-relays

tor project faq points to this page: https://metrics.torproject.org/. But it is not easy to understand. I don't understand the terms used in this page.

How do I decipher the following information from this page:

1. Total number of exit nodes active are : xxxxx
2. Total number of relays active are : xxxxxx

Comment: related https://superuser.com/questions/182902/how-many-tor-exit-nodes-are-there

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to look at:

https://metrics.torproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options.

1. Have a look at: http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

If you scroll right to the bottom of the page you'll find a box labelled "Aggregate Network Statistic Summary". In here there's a field for the total number of exit routers. The number of relays is, I believe, in the row showing the total number of routers.

2. https://metrics.torproject.org

You've already linked to this. You'll find it difficult to get exact figures, but the graph you want is the second in the list: "Relays with Exit, Fast, Guard, Stable, and HSDir flags". The "Running" plot shows all running relays, while the "Exit" plot shows exit nodes.